# Remove trailing comma from line of text generated by final iteration of loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am creating lines of text to be consumed by another layer in my application.  The lines are:

```
['Jun 13',529],

['Jul 13',550],

['Aug 13',1005],

['Sep 13',1021],

['Oct 13',1027],
```

What is the fastest/easiest way to remove the trailing comma from the last line of text?

I'm expecting something like this:

```
['Jun 13',529],

['Jul 13',550],

['Aug 13',1005],

['Sep 13',1021],

['Oct 13',1027]
```

**Actual Code:**

```
$i = 0;
while($graph_data = $con->db_fetch_array($graph_data_rs))
{
    $year = $graph_data['year'];
    $month = $graph_data['month'];
    $count = $graph_data['count'];
    $total_count = $graph_data['total_count'];

    // for get last 2 digits of year
    $shortYear = substr($year, -2, 2);

    // for get month name in Jan,Feb format
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1);
    $monthName = date('M', $timestamp );
    
    $data1 = "['".$monthName.'&nbsp;'.$shortYear."',".$total_count."],";

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: It's kind of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I think

Comment: By the way, if you are building array by dynamically adding key->value pairs, you can leave last comma and it will be ok (will work)

Comment: That's not much of an array, more of a string. Making it stupidly hard to parse. Why not create an actual array, then `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you have that array in a variable and want a string, you can use [implode](http://php.net/implode) to get a string separated by a *glue* char.
- If you already have an string, you can use [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim) to remove the last char to the right of the string.
- If you have an array, where the value is a string `['Oct 13',1027]` (ending in a comma), you have the same options above and:

  - You can use [array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk) with some of the mentioned functions
  - You can get the last element, and use [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim) on it like the code below:

Example of code using [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim) on a array of strings:

```
<?php
$values = array("['Oct 13',1027],", "['Oct 13',1027],");
$lastIndex = count($values)-1;
$lastValue = $values[$lastIndex];
$values[$lastIndex] = rtrim($lastValue, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "['Jun 13',529],",
    "['Jul 13',550],"
);
$arr[] = rtrim(array_pop($arr), ', \t\n\r');
print_r($arr);

// output:

// Array
// (
//     [0] => ['Jun 13',529],
//     [1] => ['Jul 13',550]
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it an actual array, and implode. Not really sure what is is going to be (if json:you can do even better and not make the values themselves fake-arrays, but this is left as an exersize to the reader).

```
$yourData = array();
while(yourloop){
     //probaby something like: $yourData = array($monthName=>$total_count);
    $yourData[] = "['".$monthName.'&nbsp;'.$shortYear."',".$total_count."]";
}
//now you have an actual array with that data, instead of a fake-array that's a string.
//recreate your array like so:
$data1 = implode(','$yourData);
//or use json_encode.
```

Comment: why? This is should get you going -> put your stuff in an array, and then you should look at json_encode

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to @srain but using `array_push`.

```
$values = array("['Oct 13',1027],", "['Oct 13',1027],");

$last = array_pop($values); //pop last element
array_push( $values, rtrim($last, ',') ); //push it by removing comma

var_dump($values);

//output
/*

array
  0 => string '['Oct 13',1027],' (length=16)
  1 => string '['Oct 13',1027]' (length=15)

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

@ElonThan [was right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360742/php-remove-the-comma-from-last-item-of-the-an-array#comment28686838_19360742) and [so was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360742/php-remove-the-comma-from-last-item-of-the-an-array/68336289#comment28686891_19360742) @BenFortune. This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329), and none of the other answers are giving you the best advice -- **"Never craft your own json string manually"**.

You *think* you just need to remove the final comma from your textual output so that it creates something that javascript can parse as an indexed array of indexed arrays.

What you *should* be doing is creating a multidimensional array then converting that data into a json string.  PHP has a native function that does exactly this AND it guarantees that you will have a valid json string (because it will escape characters as needed).

I'll demonstrate how to adjust your script based on your `while()` loop.

```
$result = [];
while ($row = $con->db_fetch_array($graph_data_rs)) {
    $result[] = [
        date('M y', strtotime($row['year'] . '-' . $row['month'])),
        $row['total_count']
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here is an online demo that re-creates your query's result set as an input array, then replicates the loop and result generation.  https://3v4l.org/cG66l

Then all you have to do is echo that string into your rendered html document's javascript where required.